# Flutter independencies

Tags: flutter-dependencies

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final wordPair = WordPair.random();
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.purple[900]),
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text('WorldPair Generator')),
            `enter code here`body: Center(child: Text(wordPair.asPascaLCase))));
```

ERROR MESSAGE:
lib/main.dart:10:22: Error: The getter 'WordPair' isn't defined for the class 'MyApp'.

- 'MyApp' is from 'package:api_app/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'WordPair'.
  final wordPair = WordPair.random();
  ^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 0):

You can in `pubspec.yaml` add `english_words: any` in `dependencies` and click `Pub get` 
See picture below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the author of `english_words` has actually turned off that command, so it doesnt work, But if you want to generate some random words, you can use the `SuperHeroName Generator` from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev)